# Delayed Job - Mail is not sending for spreadsheet data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, csv, paperclip

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` & `gem 'daemons'` for sending an emails.

Also I am importing a data from `.csv` and `.xls` file to my database. After saving an object I am trying to send an email using delay, but right now mail is sending only for data which is imported from `.csv` file. Mail is not sending for the data which is imported from `.xls` file.

I am using `gem 'roo'` for extracting `xls` file data.

In delayed_jobs table for spreadsheet data, `handler` field contains like below,

```
raw_attributes:
name: User1
email: &5 !ruby/string:Spreadsheet::Link
  str: user1@gmail.com
  url: mailto:user1@gmail.com
  fragment:
```

In the same delayed_jobs table for csv data, `handler` field contains like below,

```
raw_attributes:
name: "User2\tuser2@gmail.com\t111111333"
id: 7
email: 
mobile_number:
```

I am extracting xls file data like below,

```
def extract_asset_data_from_xls(asset)
  require 'spreadsheet'
  filename = "#{Rails.root}/#{asset.document.path}"
  if File.exist?(filename)
    file = File.open(filename)
    if file
      worksheet = Spreadsheet.open(file).worksheet(0)
      1.upto worksheet.last_row_index do |index|
        row = worksheet.row(index)
        user = User.new
        user.name = row[0]
        user.email = row[1]
        user.save
      end
    end
  else
    puts "#{filename} doesn't exists".red
    return
  end
end
```

How can I send an email to spreadsheet's data using `delay`?

Comment: I think you might have to provide more information. How are you currently attempting to send the email? How are you doing it differently from sending the email for csv data? I would be great to see that code.

Comment: I am using single method for both csv and xls data.

Comment: `Email.delay(:queue => 'other').deliver_welcome_mail(user)`

Comment: Call `sheet.to_csv` from `roo` and then use your proven-to-work csv handler. The problem is that `roo` tries to save all the formatting.